# How to know whether a cell contains Gujarati or English letters?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If the contents of the cells in Google sheet are as per the below image:

[image]

Then in Apps Script, how can we check whether it includes Gujarati letters or not.

```
function containsGujaratFont() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetNameToWriteHere");
  var vals = sheet.getRange("B1:B3").getValues();
  vals.forEach(r => {
    Logger.log(includesGujaratiFont(r[0]));
  });
}

function includesGujaratiFont(str){
  // some coding to identify if str contains Gujarati characters or not
  if(itContainsGujaratiFont){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

The log should be:

```
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, when [this information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_(Unicode_block)) is used, it is considered that the range of Unicode is `\u0A80-\u0AFF`. When this range is used in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, your function of `includesGujaratiFont` is modified.

```js
function includesGujaratiFont(str){
  return /^[\u0A80-\u0AFF]+$/.test(str);
}
```

- In this modification, when all characters in a cell value are Gujarati, `true` is returned.
- If you want to return `true`, at least when one of the characters in a cell value is Gujarati, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      return /^[\u0A80-\u0AFF]+$/.test(str);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      return /[\u0A80-\u0AFF]/.test(str);
    ```

#### References:

- [Gujarati (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_(Unicode_block))
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Thank you very much. It served my purpose. In PDF, Gujarati fonts occupy more white space and the line spacing is too high. While the English fonts shrinks in PDF and occupy less space than the sheet. Compare all data in Sheet and PDF. I am trying to set the row height (forced) manually, so that I can identify the page breaks in PDF, and I can manage the page breaks. I am trying in this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-ZxAncZM2-aG8qEcc1ZA_tN2NzwLme0OB-p5SNDnuQ/edit?usp=sharing). Run from custom menu "Row Heights".

Comment: When we keep Top margin 0.6 and bottom margin 0.258, then after sum of row heights = 1260 there will be a page break. See this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQTIpNqFLE6dF06bcShiSjJWyJYKzZn3/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Ok, I will create a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use app script to do this. You can use the [DETECTLANGUAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093278?hl=en-GB) funtion within google sheets.

If you enter the following formula into cell B2, where your text is in A2, the formula will then output GU for Gujarati.

```
=detectlanguage(A2)
```

The only limitation on this function is if the cell contains two lanagaues i.e. Gujarati and English it will only work for the first text element

Comment: Thanks for replying. Good option. But I want to use it in Apps script and many of my cells include both fonts (characters).